# Result like Oracle query in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, sql-order-by

In Oracle for e.g.

```
create table test1(Prod_Name varchar2(30))
insert into test1 values('CHANNEL')
insert into test1 values('SHELL')
insert into test1 values('_DISTRIBUTOR BELT')
select * from test1 order by prod_name asc
```

Select query gives the following result

```
Prod_Name
CHANNEL
SHELL
_DISTRIBUTOR BELT
```

but in SQL Server it giving following result

```
Prod_Name
_DISTRIBUTOR BELT
CHANNEL
SHELL
```

I want the result to be the same as Oracle in SQL Server so how to write query. To clarify, I want  CHANNEL, SHELL, and _DISTRIBUTOR BELT row in last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server you can force the collation when using COLLATE. Try this below script and you should get your expected output this way.

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=65bfe5a47b9a5ba708a8cb9142122e99)

```
SELECT * 
FROM test1 
ORDER BY prod_name 
    COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN2
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky. Oracle and SQL Server have different sorting rules. Oracle by default does *binary sort*, which is based on *the numeric values of the characters defined by the character encoding scheme* (this is the fastest method).

The underscore character (`_`) has ASCII code 95, while A-Z range from 65 to 90. Hence the results that you are seeing.

One way to produce the expected results is to do a *linguistic sort*: with this setting, characters are sorted *independently of their numeric values in the character encoding scheme*.

I played around with the parameters, and here is a solution that sorts as expected:

```
select * from test1 order by nlssort(prod_name, 'nls_sort = punctuation')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=420823738da3053f3ed709c89ce66537)**

Please note that this will be slower than doing a binary sort.